# pandas.to_latex - how escape latex symbols but only for selected columns?

Tags: pandas, latex

How can I enable Latex symbol escaping in `pandas.to_latex` function but only for selected columns? Is it also possible to enable\disable symbol escaping only for indexes and column names?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Styler.format(escape="latex", subset=[col1, col3])` pattern selecting your columns that you want to apply the formatting to.